# Power BI Card (new) visual - how to count items per week, month, quarter from the column?

Tags: powerbi, card

I am using Power BI desktop, and I need to create a "Card (new)" visual to show the number of distinct IDs per last week, last month, last quarter, last year (or better for selected week, month, quarter, year from the list of available in the whole table).
My "Card (new)" visual has field wells "Data" and "Tooltips".
And my table "conversations" has columns "id" with data like "1aa-2bb3-4ccc2" and "updatedAt" with date in format “MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM”. I also created a new Measure which has a number of the week of the year, extracted from "updatedAt" column:

```
UpdatedAtWeek = WEEKNUM('conversations'[updatedAt] + 1) +
              IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR('conversations'[updatedAt]), 1, 1)) = 7, -1, 0)
```

Is it possible to group by that UpdatedAtWeek value, and count unique ids in time range of week, month, quarter (last one or chosen from all available)?

Comment: Do you have a Date/Calendar table? It is in this table where you'd have Weeks, Months, Quarters, Years etc... And in your `conversations` table, consider having a Date column (or spliting the DateTime column into Date and Time columns, then you can then have a relationship to the Date/Calendar table.

Comment: No, I have just 2 columns in the table. And Measure created by me. Should I create a separate Calendar table? And how does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Date or Calendar table helps because you can use DAX [Time Intelligence functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax), and do the groupings that you are after.

The Date table will be the Dimension table to your 'Fact' table. You would use the Date table for your slicers/filters.

You can create a Date table in PowerQuery, DAX as a Calculated Table, or even import it from a data source/warehouse - do a search, you'll find many examples.

An example DAX Calculate Table could look like:

```
Dim Date =
  ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "Month", FORMAT([Date], "MMM"),
    "MonthNum", MONTH([Date]),
    "Year", YEAR([Date]),
    "Year-Month", FORMAT([Date], "yyyy-MM"),
    "Quarter", FORMAT( QUARTER([Date]), "\Q#"),
    "Year-Quarter", FORMAT([Date], "\Yyy-") & FORMAT( QUARTER([Date]), "\Q#"),
    "WeekNum", WEEKNUM([Date], 16) // this is equivalent to your [UpdatedAtWeek]
  )
```

Once created:

- Click on the `Month` column in the `Dim Date` table, then `Sort by column` in the ribbon, and select `MonthNum`. This will ensure Jan, Feb etc... will be ordered correctly.
- Right-click on `Dim Date` table and select `Mark as date table` and in the pop-up select `Date` as the Date column.

Then for your `conversations` table - create a Calculated Column just for the Date:

```
Date = DATE( YEAR([updatedAt]), MONTH([updatedAt]), DAY([updatedAt]) )
```

Next, add a one-to-many relationship from `Dim Date` to `conversations` table on the `Date` columns.

Lastly, create a new measure for the count of your conversations:

```
Conversation Count = DISTINCTCOUNTNONBLANK('conversations'[id])
```

Now you can use `[Conversation Count]` in your card, and use any of the columns in `Dim Date` to do your "grouping" via slicers/filters.

Comment: I approve this answer, Thank you very much, @Sam Nsier! After I dragged necessary fields from Dim Data to the report, it all works fine, I can select time range and visualize the count in report page.